# App crashes on users devices while loading or reloading uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, reloaddata

I am trying to fix a chrash that is not reproducible on any of our test devices. The App crashes numerous times (60k times) as these are being reported on crashlytics. The same crash is being reported differently in crashlytics. But i think both are the same.

Crash 1
[image]

Crash 2

[image]

Both crashes are of the same kind.

I have 2 different delegate methods that are triggered up the chain.

1st delegate method has the below code and this method is implemented by UITableviewcell.

```
- (void)flightSegment:(FlightSegmentViewController *)flightSegmentController didChangeHeightWith:(CGFloat)heightDelta {
int index = [flightSegmentControllers indexOfObject:flightSegmentController];   //Shows warning as indexOfObject returns NSUInteger rather than int. Could this be the problem? if it is then it should crash in all the devices. 

[UIView beginAnimations:@"originAndDestinationAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

for (int i = index + 1; i < flightSegmentControllers.count; i++) {
    FlightSegmentViewController *vc = [flightSegmentControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    CGRect frame = vc.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y += heightDelta;
    vc.view.frame = frame;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];

[delegate bookingCell:self didChangeHeightWith:heightDelta];
```

}

2nd delegate method has the below code. This delegate method is implemented by the actual TableViewContoller.

```
- (void)bookingCell:(XXXGMBookingCell *)theBookingCell didChangeHeightWith:(CGFloat)heightDelta {
[menuTableView beginUpdates];
[menuTableView endUpdates];

[self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:menuTableView afterDelay:0.333f];
```

}

Can someone guide where this is crashing?? My main intension is to reproduce the issue on my test devices and then try to fix it.

**EDIT**

```
- (void)disruptionBannerShow {
NSInteger numOfRowsInSectionNul = [self tableView:menuTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
if (numOfRowsInSectionNul == 0) {
    [menuTableView beginUpdates];
    NSArray *insertedRows = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [menuTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [menuTableView endUpdates];
}
[self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:menuTableView afterDelay:0.33333f];
```

}

AND ALSO

```
- (void)disruptionBannerHide {
NSInteger numOfRowsInSectionNul = [self tableView:menuTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
if (numOfRowsInSectionNul > 0) {
    [menuTableView beginUpdates];
    NSArray *deletedRows = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [menuTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deletedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [menuTableView endUpdates];
}
[self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:menuTableView afterDelay:0.33333f];
```

}

I have few other places where the i am inserting & deleting something. Can any one see a mistake in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens because your update of your table is incorrect. 
The crash says that number of rows in a section do not match up. Post the code where you add cells to the sections or where you remove them. After you delete/add rows, your function `numberOfRowsInSection` is called again, where you are returning the old count.

Comment: @Rajashekar I hope you don't get frustrated over this. But it will be very difficult for people to see mistake in your logic. After every deletion/updation, make sure your numberOfRowsInSection would return the correct values as well. 
Put breakpoints in your code and make sure the values are correct or not.